# In XSLT using XPath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, substring, trim

if I have number like $999,999 I want to use a function to give me just 999999 without any other symbol.I tried substring(value,2) but that take of the $ how about the , Is there any idea to do that,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate('$999,999', '$,', '')"/>
```

Comment: actually it works fine with me but how if the value I'm getting its attribute can I do it like this <xsl:value-of select="translate('@value', '$,', '')"/>

Comment: @SalehMakkawy Yes, you can.. Just get single quotes off `@value` so that it is evaluated, and not considered a literal string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the value is actually a string, instead of a number.  If you are using XPath 2.0, you can use [`replace`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace) (eg `replace(substring(value,2), ',', '')`).

If you are using XPath 1.0 (more widely supported) you can using [`translate`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate) (eg `translate(substring(value,2), ',', '')`).

Comment: Your approach will fail in case of a negative amount, e.g. `"-$123"`.